# Дефекты локализации в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, страница-учётной-записи

Пробежался по профилю и вот, что наскреб.

1. **Сразу нашлось**: *consecutive* и *all actions*

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

2. **В сокращенном режиме**: *reputation*

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

3. **В режиме редактирования** текст подсказки к дате не влезает в поле:
   [image: введите описание изображения здесь]
4. **Вкладка "Доступ":** *used*
   [image: введите описание изображения здесь]
   Дефект до сих пор имеет место быть, хотя вопрос и помечен как [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be):

   [image: used вчера]

В "профиле на Мете", соответственно, те же дефекты.

Comment: Тут сейчас все очень криво :).

Comment: Если уж говорить про профили, то стоит обратить внимание на title страницы, в котором пропущен пробел.

Comment: Дата рождения когда-то уже чинилась поэтому отмечаю как [meta-tag:статус-завершено]. Сегодня это снова сломалось, так что завожу новый баг. [Нет строки для локализации поля ввода даты рождения при редактировании профиля](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2397)

Comment: @NickVolynkin это нормальная практика заводить новый баг, если старый отмечен как “завершено”, но при этом всё равно проявляется?

Comment: @alexolut тут несколько разных багов описано и не все из них снова проявляются. Поэтому целесообразнее завести новый багрепорт только про один баг. Имхо, вообще надо на один баг заводить 1 тикет, нельзя свалки делать. Всё как с вопросами на SO. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin когда страница просто кишит багами, создавать на каждый из них отдельный вопрос слишком накладно. Вот если бы за них платили :) хотя бы репой...

Comment: @alexolut да, на Мете можно в лучшем случае Сократа заработать за багрепорты ))

Comment: @alexolut а ещё, я думаю, это неплохое приложение к резюме тестировщика.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не воспроизводится?

Comment: @alexolut ваша тревога тут была, я по ней убрал метку. Видимо, промахнулся.

Comment: @NickVolynkin несогласованно работаете, господа модераторы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверил, в данный момент исправлено всё, кроме подсказки для поля даты рождения. Там сейчас используется непереведённый текст. (Хотя в [[Transifex:4817]](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266729?key=e54c2c1f49b8e8183d8b4879cd7e3830) строка переведена.)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Немного сократил строку:

> ГГГГ/ММ/ДД, только для отображения возраста

Этот вариант входит в поле:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осталось добиться, чтобы движок сайта использовал переведённую строку.