# Нет строки для локализации поля ввода даты рождения при редактировании профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация, нет-в-transifex, страница-учётной-записи

Редактирование профиля пользователя, пустое поле даты рождения :

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше для этого была строка [[Transifex:4817]](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266729?key=e54c2c1f49b8e8183d8b4879cd7e3830). Теперь она, похоже, удалена. Другой на замену этой не появилось.

После починки должно быть так:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше эта проблема уже отмечалась и решалась, но теперь возникла снова. [Дефекты локализации в профиле](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10/181472)

https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266729?key=e54c2c1f49b8e8183d8b4879cd7e3830