# Доступ used вчера

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, страница-учётной-записи

Дефект из [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5) под п.4 до сих пор имеет место быть, хотя вопрос и помечен как [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be):

[image: used вчера]

Comment: @NickVolynkin можно узнать, Вы на основании собственной проверки выставляете тег, или кто-то другой воспроизвел и Вам пришла установка на добавление тега?

Comment: Иду в свой профиль, смотрю - баг есть.  Отмечаю. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin тогда очень странно, что этот тег так редко/долго появляется на вопросах с дефектами.